# Fixing broken packages on debian

Tags: python, apt-get

I have a debian (wheezy) box that has gotten into a screwy state.  I can't install or remove any python-related packages with apt-get (including upgrading or downgrading python itself), I get this:

```
# apt-get -f install
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.3-6+deb7u2) ...
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: error processing python2.7-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-minimal:
 python-minimal depends on python2.7-minimal (>= 2.7.3-1~); however:
  Package python2.7-minimal is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-minimal (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python2.7:
 python2.7 depends on python2.7-minimal (= 2.7.3-6+deb7u2); however:
  Package python2.7-minimal is not configured yet.
```

(and then a million other errors like that).

How to recover from this state?

(Note: I got into this state by trying to install python-scikit from jessie on a system that is wheezy with some wheezy-backports)

Comment: I believe you have to disable dependancy checking as well.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get check` and `sudo dpkg -C`.